# How Bootload an Lilypad Arduino USB using Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, bootloader

I recently bought two lilypads USB, one works perfectly (it's recognized in my computer, but the other one it's never recognized, I even try in different computers and the same scenario with both devices)

[image]

So I think that maybe the second one doesn't have a bootloader installed. So I'm triying to "burn" a new bootloader. I have been triying following the guide on https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP using as programmer an Arduino UNO but without luck. I ever get avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying). Thanks for the help!

Comment: If it is showing up in the Device Manager as Arduino Lilypad USB then *something* is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try uploading to a LilyPad USB with the wrong board selected, you may end up in a condition where the bootloader can no longer respond normally.

You can get the LilyPad Arduino into bootloader mode by tapping the reset button twice in under a second. Once in bootloader mode, the LED should blink at about 1Hz for about 8 seconds. My advice is to load a blank sketch (i.e., nothing in loop() or setup()) and then double tap the reset button shortly after hitting the upload button. That should restore the LilyPad USB to a working state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this solution but same situation, even worse the LED never blink. Also it's imposible try to load something because the board it's never recognized by the IDE so I can't try to upload something. Finally I decided return the item.

Answer (score 0):

The Lilypad is an official Arduino board. If you did not get it from other continents, it should have the bootloader in so don't try to burn something else. Check the traces of your Lilypad. Some short might occur because of and accidental short.

Whatever you do, DON'T TRY TO BURN SOMETHING THAT DOESN'T NEED TO BE BURNED.

Comment: Yes, essentially, if it doesn't work out of the box it should be returned - especially if it is from a less than reputable source rather than from one of the claimants to the Arduino name.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's true if it's not working out the box I should return the item. Thanks!